# IE duplicating a server side Break <br>

Tags: html, vb.net, break, runat

I have a issue with two breaks < Br /> appearing in IE,

If I have a normal break placed like so

```
<wcl:GridView ....... />
<br />
<wcl:Button runat="server" ID="btnAddAnotherQuote" OnClientClick='AddDeliveryQuote(this);return false;' />
<wcl:HelpDialog runat="server" ID="hdDeliveryQuotes" />
```

Then it appears in Firefox and IE fine.
But if i Do it like so:

```
<br runat="server" id="brAddAnotherQuote" />
<wcl:Button runat="server" ID="btnAddAnotherQuote" OnClientClick='AddDeliveryQuote(this);return false;' />
<wcl:HelpDialog runat="server" ID="hdDeliveryQuotes" />
```

Then looking at the source code for IE, it produces two 
 
Once which has a ID of brAddAnotherQuote and one which is simple "< br />" directly under it
This doesn't happen in Firefox

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why dont you try something like following in place of server side br tag.

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" id="brAddAnotherQuote" Text="<br />"></asp:Literal>
```